# Error Handling in Service Worker When response.ok is False

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm a novice in JS & functional programming. I need to implement a service worker to cache static assets. In the following code what should be done when the response.ok is false?

```
    ev.respondWith(
      fetch(ev.request)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            // this part is done and working
          } else {
            // what should be done here? Should the response be returned
            // and let the UI handle the error, like the following?
            return res;
            // or nothing?
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => caches.match(ev.request).then((res) => res))
    );
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe the else part is not required, you can just return the response outside of if block.